# New app is not shown up on openshift

Tags: java, web-applications, war, openshift

I have deployed a Java webapp (.war) file on openshift tomcat container using rhc client tolls on windows. Then app is deployed successfully (I named app ROOT.war). My app address is (http://easytravelapp-easytravel.rhcloud.com/). However when I open the address I got same default web page i.e. "Welcome to OpenShift". Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a README in your repo's root dir.  In section "Details about layout and deployment options", there are instructions to run "git remove -r src/ pom.xml" along with adding your war and running git add/commit/push.  That should remove the source of the sample app.